# Why does a homomorphism have no Eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

So I can explain it with the definition of an eigenvalue, that a linear map f: V -> W has no eigenvalues. because an Eigenvalue by definition is the value c element of a Field, such that g(v)=c*v holds, meaning that c is the scaling factor of the vector v applied by the linear transformation g.
Since V is a vector space and v is an element of V, it follows that c*v must be an element of V.

Now assume f: V -> W and  V != W (not equal). I cant really grasp, how there cant be any eigenvalue for this linear map. I can only explain it by the definition, but id like to understand it intuitively.

For example imagine a linear map f: V -> W with a determinant greater than 0. how can this have no eigenvalues?

I might have to study linear maps more and understand, what it truely means to map into another vector space or to the same vector space. But I am thinking, when the determinant is not zero and the linear map preserves its dimension, how can there be no eigenvalues? I dont really get it.

p.s. i dont fully know how to format, but I think i explained it well.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thank you! I‘ll check it out.

Comment: According to your definition of eigenvalues, it is possible to have an eigenvalue if $V \ne W$ but $V \subseteq W$. For example, the inclusion map $V \to W$ has eigenvalue one. On the other hand, the convention is that eigenvalues and eigenvectors are defined only on maps $V \to V$. But that is just a convention; there is nothing deep to understand about it.

Comment: thank you! Your comment helped a lot! ^^